# Best way to transfer a table in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Let's assume we have the same Cassandra version on both servers, and Ubuntu 13.04 and 14.04 OSes (both x64). Cassandra version is 2.0.6.

We have 1 single-node server where all production data is stored. Yes, it's a single-node cluster, and we will not make it multi-node in the nearest future for some reasons. Let's call that server Production. There's also another server, where a new piece of data is prepared. Let's call it Worker. There's a Database and a Table.

We can't perform data processing directly on the Production server because it consumes a lot of CPU and memory. So we use another Worker server - it's not a disaster even if it freezes or fails.

Basically, **I want to swap the table files - get the new data, push it into the Production server with some different name, delete the old table and rename that new data back.**

More informative:

1) on the Worker: run scripts that perform data processing so I will have the Table stored on the HDD of the Worker server

2) rename the Table on the Worker server to Table_new

3) rsync the Table_new files to the Production server

4) install somehow there files there so our Production Cassandra will be aware of the new table

5) on the Production server, check the Table_new if everything is ok

6) delete the Table (old table) on the Production server, and rename the Table_new into Table

So, finally, there should be an updated Table on the Production server, but with the data actually produced by the Worker server and transferred to the Production server with minimum efforts and downtime.

I'm not going to transfer the whole database, it should remain unchanged - but only the tables. My concern is that there might be issues related to the database-table inconsistency. Or that some table data is cached\stored somewhere, and after I delete the old and push the new, it might throw exceptions.

Is that possible? I don't want to perform the classic export\import things, they are relatively slow and may lead to a longer downtime.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just insert the data from the worker into the production server?  How are you generating the new table data?  Does the data contain deletes?  Or just updates?  Do you really want to truncate/drop the existing data?

Answer (score 3):

So if you really do want to lose the current data.  And you generated sstable files to put into the system.  The easiest way to do this would be to:

1. Copy new files to the server into a folder on the same mount point as the data directory, but outside the data directory.
2. Issue a truncate command on the existing table from cqlsh.
3. Hard link the new data into the right data directory for the table (which is now empty)
4. Run `nodetool refresh <keyspace> <cf-name>` to load the new sstables.

If you don't want to lose the existing data, you can skip step 2.

When you move to a more than 1 node cluster, you will need to use the "sstableloader" command to send the new files into the system, so they get distributed to the right nodes.